# Post Message on Friends Facebook Wall post in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on an application in which I have to post a greeting to my friends' wall through my account.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *parmaDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
[parmaDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello world"] forKey:@"message"]; // if you want send message  
[parmaDic setObject:@"http://icon.png" forKey:@"picture"];  // if you want send picture    
[parmaDic setObject:@"Create post" forKey:@"name"];         // if you want send name    
[parmaDic setObject:@"Write description." forKey:@"description"]; // if you want  description

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",facebook_user_id] 
                      andParams:parmaDic 
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

I use key like.message,picture ..etc please see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/